# During user log in process change button class and text?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have a login form

```
    @using (Html.BeginForm("Login", "Account", new { ReturnUrl = ViewBag.ReturnUrl }, FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form-horizontal", role = "form" }))
    {
        .....
        .....            

        <input type="submit" value="Log in" class="btn btn-primary" />

        <p>
            @Html.ActionLink("Register", "Register") if you don't have a local account.
        </p>
    }
</section>
```

While the process of logging in is running in background, what should I do to change the button class and text.
For example, change button class to `btn btn-info` and text to `Logging in...`

Should I change the way I have created my Form (using Html Helpers)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1 Give some name or id to your submit button, e.g "btnLogin"

2 Use jQuery to bind the click event of this button like following:

```
$("#btnLogin").click(function(){
    $(this).toggleClass("btn btn-info").val("Logging in...");
});
```

I haven't used any code editor to check my code but I hope it will give you a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

you can try with this code : use it in  onClick function.

```
 document.getElementById('btn btn-info').value = 'Logging in...';
```

**Update:** This can also helpful

```
$("#btnLogin").click(function(){
     document.getElementById('btn btn-info').value = 'Logging in...';
});
```